# Python stops working when using pip

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip

When I try to install new modules from pip, using PowerShell on Windows 7, using Python 2.7, I get an error message saying Python has stopped working. Like so:
[installing nose directly from pip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tt8kv.jpg). As given in the above screenshot, my command prompt has the following:

```
> python -m pip install nose
Collecting nose
```

...followed by a Windows dialog box popping up saying that "python.exe has stopped working", offering to check online for a solution.

---

I can however install modules after downloading them but I still get the error message after it has been installed: [installing nose from the wheel file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OsB4Y.jpg)

```
> python -m pip install .\nose-1.3.7-py2-none-any.whl
Processing d:\python\nose-1.3.7-py2-none-any.whl
Collecting installed packages: nose
Successfully installed nose-1.3.7
```

...however, the same "python.exe has stopped working" dialog occurs.

---

I also get the same error when I try to upgrade some module.

How should I fix this?

Comment: I'd reinstall python, personally.

Comment: A question that isn't complete enough to answer without following off-site links isn't acceptable here. I've edited accordingly.